# Android Studio: Checkbox Listener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I have a CheckBox with an ID checkBox1, which will be controlled and set automatically. I would like to listen to the state of the CheckBox and change the position of a RadioButton with ID radioButton1 which is in different activity. I know how to display a text when the checkbox is clicked. Is there a way how to make the RadioButton listen to the state of the CheckBox?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

there are many way to do that you can use broadcaster receiver, livedata, interface and intent . those are will work for you. try to implement interface it can be easier.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never used Android Studio or the Android SDK.

I searched "android checkbox listener" on Google and this is the first result: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.

> To define the click event handler for a checkbox, add the android:onClick attribute to the  element in your XML layout. The value for this attribute must be the name of the method you want to call in response to a click event. The Activity hosting the layout must then implement the corresponding method.